# Javascript Copy to Clipboard for dynamically created controls

Tags: javascript

I wanted to use Javascript Copy to Clipboard function for the dynamically created controls. My requirement is as below:

[image]

for the static controls where id is present, it's pretty simple but for the dynamically created controls, it does not work.

```
function myFunction() {
    /* Get the text field */
    var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput");

    /* Select the text field */
    copyText.select();
    copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999); /* For mobile devices */

    /* Copy the text inside the text field */
    document.execCommand("copy");

    /* Alert the copied text */
    alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
}
```

How to make Copy to Clipboard working for the dynamically created controls?

Answer (score 1):

To implement copy to clipboard for the dynamically created controls you could use the following javascript function.

Logic is as follows:

1. When copy action happens, it adds a text field dynamically under the body and sets the value you wish to copy to this dynamic text input
2. From the dynamically created input using it copies the text using standard javascript methods such as   xxx.select() and document.execCommand("copy");
3. Once the copy action is done remove the dynamically added input.

So every time it adds control and removes it once the purpose is done. It happens so fast that nobody can even notice it.

Here is the method readily available for you:

```
function copyTextToClipboard(textToCopy) {

    /* Append an input:type=text under the body*/
    $("body").append("<div id=\"divCopyToClipboard\"><input type=\"text\" id=\"txtCopyToClipboard\" value=\"" + textToCopy + "\"></div>");

    /* Set the value which user wish to copy to clipboard*/
    $("#txtCopyToClipboard").val(textToCopy);

    /* Get the control object*/
    var copyText = document.getElementById("txtCopyToClipboard");


    /* Select the text field */
    copyText.select();
    copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999); /* For mobile devices */

    /*Copy the text inside the text field */
    document.execCommand("copy");

    /* Alert the copied text */
    alert("Copied the variable: " + textToCopy);

    /* Finally remove the dynamically created field*/
    $("#divCopyToClipboard").remove();
}
```

Hope you find it useful.